# How to add a discount to quote

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, discount

I want to know if there is a way to set a `discount` to `quote` `before paying` ?

I would like to set a `percent discount` if customer select special payment.

Thanks.

Comment: You can observ event and based on payment method set your discount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Discount to total

**config.xml:**

```
<global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <discount>
                    <class>Company_Module_Model_Discount</class>
                    <after>subtotal</after>
                </discount>
            </totals>
        </quote>    
        <order_invoice>
            <totals>
                <discount>
                    <class>Company_Module_Model_Invoice</class>
                    <after>subtotal</after>
                </discount>
            </totals>
        </order_invoice>
        <order_creditmemo>
            <totals>
                <discount >
                    <class>Company_Module_Model_Creditmemo</class>
                    <after>subtotal</after>
                </discount>
            </totals>
        </order_creditmemo>
    </sales>
</global>
```

This code will allow you to add a custom value to: quote, order invoice and order credit memo controllers. Also with the help of tags: `<after>` and `<before>` it is possible to define the discount calculation procedure here. It needs to be done in order to define the value (subtotal, total etc) to calculate discount. In the example below the discount of subtotal meaning is calculated.

The next step is to create **classes specified** in `config.xml` file which will calculate the discount.

**Discount.php:**

```
class Company_Module_Model_Discount extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{

    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        if ($address->getData('address_type') == 'billing')
        return $this; 

        $discount = 15; //your discount percent               
        $grandTotal = $address->getGrandTotal();
        $baseGrandTotal = $address->getBaseGrandTotal();
        $totals = array_sum($address->getAllTotalAmounts());
        $baseTotals = array_sum($address->getAllBaseTotalAmounts());
        $address->setFeeAmount(-$totals * $discount / 100);
        $address->setBaseFeeAmount(-$baseTotals * $discount / 100);
        $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal + $address->getFeeAmount());
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal + $address->getBaseFeeAmount());
        return $this;
    }

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {  
        if ($address->getData('address_type') == 'billing')
        return $this;

        $amt = $address->getDiscountAmount();
        if ($amt != 0) {
            $address->addTotal(array(
                                  'code' => 'Discount',
                                  'title' => 'Discount',
                                  'value' => $amt
            ));
        }
        return $address;
    }

}
```

**Note:** Total value is calculated for all addresess (could be billing and shipping, or multiple shipping addresses, etc.) indicated in quote, that's why it is essential to calculate the discount only for the shipping address, in other cases the discount will appear twice. To avoid this situation, run the address verification first and only after the verification, perform discount calculations and pass the results to Total collection. The method: `fetch()` is responsible for displaying the discount. Thus, if all done well, the discount should appear on Checkout and Cart pages